# Capture data from Tkinter (Button and OptionMenu) to the database (POSTGRESQL)

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter

Today I have a problem that I would like to present to you. I am making a form in python that uses POSTGRESQL as database. It is giving me an error because when it wants to access the menu information when it is going to be uploaded to the database, and it is not giving me the one I chose, the same thing happens to me with a button that has an image as an attachment, I don't know how to save it to database, what function should i use for this, can you help me?

**ERROR**

```
zpsycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj
```

**This is the declaration of the dropdown menu.**

```
        self.var1 = StringVar(self.frame)
        self.opcion1 = OptionMenu(self.frame, self.var1, *ArrayComercial, command=self.getOpcion1)
        self.opcion1.config(width=20)
        self.opcion1.place(x=200, y=240)
```

**This is the button declaration that will save the attached image**

```
self.botton_ComproPago = Button(self.frame, text="Adjuntar", command=self.AbrirArchivo) 

self.botton_ComproPago.place(x=200, y=380)
```

**Function to search the image in windows**

```
        def AbrirArchivo(self):
               archivo = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="abrir", initialdir="C:/", filetypes= 
              [["Archivos de Imagen", "*.jpg"]])
              print(archivo)
```

**Button to save the information**

```
        self.botton_Guardar = Button(self.frame, text="Guardar", 
            command=lambda:self.GuardarFormulario(
            self.entry_NumeroPresu.get(),
            self.entry_Cliente.get(),
            self.entryFecha.get(),
            self.opcion1,
            self.opcion2,
            self.botton_ComproPago.cget('command'),
            self.botton_ComproProove.cget('command')
            
            ))
```

**Database connection function**

```
    def GuardarFormulario(self, Numero_Pres, Cliente, Fecha_Soli, Comercial, Asistente, 
        Compro_Pago, Compro_Proveedor):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres",
                         user="postgres", 
                         password="pass", 
                         host="localhost"
                         )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query =  "INSERT INTO 
        Formulario(NumeroPresu,Cliente,Fecha_Solic,Comercial,Asistente,Compro_Pago,Compro_Proove) 
                                                             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        info =  Numero_Pres,Cliente,Fecha_Soli,Comercial,Asistente,Compro_Pago,Compro_Proveedor
        cursor.execute(query, info)
        print("save")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

I know I need to use try except but for now with tests I'm not using it

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: @BryanOakley The post has already been updated

Comment: You passed `self.opcion1` and `self.opcion2` (which are `OptionMenu` widgets) to `self.GuardarFormulario(...)`.  I think they should be `self.var1.get()` and `self.var2.get()` instead.